# Given a set $A \subseteq \{1,2,3...150\}$ such that $|A|=25$. Prove there are $a,b,c,d\in A$ satisfying $a+b=c+d$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Given a set $A \subseteq \{1,2,3...150\}$ such that $|A|=25$. Prove using Pigeonhole Principle there are 4 different elements $a,b,c,d\in A$ satisfying $a+b=c+d$

A direction or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: How many pairs of elements can you pick to make $a+b$?

Comment: Related [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473089/let-t-be-any-subset-of-1-2-3-100-with-69-elements-prove-that-one?rq=1). The argument given in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2473342) can be applied to your question.

Answer (score 7):

The number of pairs of elements in a set of $25$ elements is $\frac{25\cdot24}{2}=300$

If you assume all of those sums (pairwise) are different, then they have to be in $\{3 \dots 299\}$ as $A \subset \{1,2\dots 150\}$. However, the set $\{3 \dots 299\}$ contains $297$ elements and hence yo get a contradiction with the assumption that all the $300$ sums are different

Answer (score 4):

Note that the statement is equivalent to that there exists $a,b,c,d\in A$ such that $a-c=d-b>0$.

Sort the elements of $A$: $a_1<a_2<\ldots <a_{25}$. Consider the sequence $$b_k=a_{k+1}-a_k,\;\;1\le k\le 24$$

If the statement is false, the elements of this sequence are pairwise different, positive integers, and hence:
$$a_{25}-a_1=\sum_{k=1}^{24}b_k\ge1+2+\cdots+24=300$$

*Remark*: With this argument, you can prove it even for $|A|=17$.

Comment: How do you know the values of $b_k$ are all distinct? Can't two successive terms $b_k,b_{k-1}$ be equal?

Comment: @ajotatxe, do you mean $|A|=18$ or $|A|=17$? 18 numbers, 17 differences. 17 numbers, 16 differences.

Comment: @quasi yes your objection is valid.  For example, 1,11,21 has distinct sums of the $\binom{3}{2}$ distinct pairs but also has equal successive differences of 10.

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{25}{2}=300$ different pairs in the chosen numbers. The sums of the elements can range from $3$ to $299$, thus can't take $300$ different values, and we conclude by the pigeon hole principle

Comment: Same as @asdf’s Answer...

Comment: The sums can range from 3 to 299. Can you explain the conclusion?

Comment: There are less than 300 integer values between 3 and 299