# Pigeonhole $a + b = c + d$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Ive got this assignment for uni where I need to prove the following:

> We have a set of $16$ different positive integers $\leq 100$, prove that there are always $a,b,c,d$ in this set so that $a + b = c + d$.

I think this is to be solved with the pigeonhole principle, but I cant quite figure it out. Does anyone know how this could be done?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Edit: a, b, c, and d are all different integers ofcourse

Comment: Some similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2586429/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2865068/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%3Dc%2Bd%24%2C%20AND%20tags%3Apigeonhole-principle)

Comment: @MartinR ohh great, thanks!

Comment: The key is that the given condition is equivalent to $$a-d=c-b$$ hence we only have to show that two pairs have the same difference , and this is in fact straight forward !

Comment: Your question was answered in this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186866/combinatorics-proof-any-set-of-16-numbers-from-1-to-100-contains-repeated-sums?noredirect=1&lq=1